Knative: helloworld-go IngressNotConfigured
I am quite new to knative, and I really need you guys' help. I was installing knative-serving by using YAML.
My environment
multipass + k3s version v1.29.3+k3s1 (8aecc26b)
disabled traefik

Knative-serving Components & Networking layer & DNS & HPA
Components knative-v1.13.1/serving-crds.yaml + knative-v1.13.1/serving-core.yaml
Networking layer knative-v1.13.0/kourier.yaml
DNS: magic DNS(sslip.io) knative-v1.13.1/serving-default-domain.yaml
Serving Extension knative-v1.13.1/serving-hpa.yaml
Everything seems well at first, then I deployed a demon, and found default-domain-xxx pods always run into error. Detailed information are as follows. I have tried troubleshooting but didnot find similar circumsatnces.
helloworld-go IngressNotConfigured
ubuntu@knative:~$ sudo kubectl get ksvc -n example
NAME            URL                                              LATESTCREATED         LATESTREADY           READY     REASON
helloworld-go   http://helloworld-go.example.svc.cluster.local/   helloworld-go-00001   helloworld-go-00001   Unknown   IngressNotConfigured

Networking Layer - Kourier looks fine
ubuntu@knative:~$ sudo kubectl -n kourier-system get service kourier
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
kourier   LoadBalancer   10.43.85.102   192.168.70.3   80:30407/TCP,443:31738/TCP   44h

But the serval pods run into error, like this
 ubuntu@knative:~$ sudo kubectl get pods -n knative-serving
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
default-domain-6gnwb                      0/1     Unknown   0             42h
default-domain-fggph                      0/1     Error     0             43h
default-domain-ksrdk                      0/1     Error     0             42h
default-domain-26msh                      0/1     Unknown   0             36h
default-domain-dlgm2                      0/1     Error     0             17h
default-domain-ctvkf                      0/1     Error     0             17h
autoscaler-78ddd8548b-8bjls               1/1     Running   3 (36m ago)   43h
net-kourier-controller-758c787975-5cvpm   1/1     Running   4 (36m ago)   43h
webhook-56bf849884-fs6qn                  1/1     Running   1 (36m ago)   15h
controller-ddf58dbc6-xvrpt                1/1     Running   6 (36m ago)   43h
autoscaler-hpa-6cc4687676-xgddk           1/1     Running   7 (36m ago)   43h
activator-56fb6f44f6-f44w9                1/1     Running   4 (36m ago)   43h

them I logs the error, but can't find solution, can you guys give me a clue? I would really really appreciate it.
ubuntu@knative:~$ sudo kubectl logs default-domain-ctvkf -n knative-serving
W0414 09:58:04.960545       1 client_config.go:618] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
{"level":"fatal","ts":1713088685.0031059,"logger":"fallback.default-domain","caller":"default-domain/main.go:204","msg":"Error finding gateway address","error":"Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook \"webhook.serving.knative.dev\": failed to call webhook: Post \"[https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/defaulting?timeout=10s](https://webhook.knative-serving.svc/defaulting?timeout=10s)\": no endpoints available for service \"webhook\"","stacktrace":"main.main\n\tknative.dev/serving/cmd/default-domain/main.go:204\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:267"}

